# How "(char*)&" magic works?

Tags: c++

When I worked with Winsock I used that code to send and receive length of message:

```cpp
int msg_size = msg.size();
send(Connection, (char*)&msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
```

and

```cpp
int msg_size;
recv(Connection, (char*)&msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
```

Also in youtube tutorials I seen code like that to write object into file:

```cpp
SomeClass someObject;
// fout is object of class ofstream
fout.write((char*)&someObject, sizeof(SomeClass));
```

And to read it:

```cpp
SomeClass someObject;
// fin is object of class ifstream
fin.read((char*)&someObject, sizeof(SomeClass));
```

But I don't understand how that magic with `(char*)&` works. I heard that it writes byte by byte in memory but still don't understand how that possible.

Comment: `&someObject` is the address of (i.e., a pointer to) `someObject`, and `(char*)` casts that to a pointer-to-`char` to treat it as a byte buffer.

Comment: first `&` it will convert object to pointer then after that it goes to convert object pointer to `(char *)`(meaning array of char's) and since it is char array and one char is one byte it's like array of one bytes.

Comment: C++ allows you to inspect the bytes of any data type by doing a `reinterpret_cast` of a pointer to this data type to `char*` or `unsigned char*`. That's basically all there is to it. Note however that code like the one presented in the question only works, if writer and reader use the same endianness; transfering the data between machines using a different endianess wont work; (One machine stores int 1 as `char[] {1,0,0,0}` the other as `char[]{0,0,0,1}`) this is even ignoring the fact that the size of `int` could differ between both programs.

Comment: C or C++? Please read the descriptions of the tags that you applied! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing magic. First, address taking operator `&` takes address of the variable, but its result type is `int *`. Then typecast operator `(char*)` forces compiler to change type to pointer to char, which then can be passes as parameter to `send()` without type violation. As result, `send()` will work with bytes in memory at that address.